# How do you best design a SQLite database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

So I have this SQLite database with two tables:

- One to store images (so it has a URL (the primary key) and an array of tags stored as a blob)
- And another one to store user's scores for trivia questions (so it has their: score, how many they've got wrong, how many they've got right and their rank).

I'm thinking of adding another table which will record details about different games users can complete too (so their level and how many wins/losses). Now the primary key for that table would be the exact same as the trivia table as the same users would be using it.

What I'm really asking is what is the best way to design this database? Should I have 3 tables or just 2? Could it be simplified more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are college-level courses on database design.

If your user table has `username`, `game1level`, `game1wins`, `game1losses`, `game2level`, `game2wins`,`game2losses`, then that's not ideal.  The game 3 code shouldn't have to deal with any other games.  Plus, adding any games requires altering your schema.  I would argue for something like:

```
user_id
game_id
level
wins
losses
```

Now you can add more data for more games without changing your tables at all.

Comment: Huh. I could have it so the trivia stuff and the game stuff do have their own columns but the game stuff is all grouped together.